# Why would writing the CTE to an actual table provide a performance improvement?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm a huge fan of CTE's. They are the best. You know it, I know it, we all know it.

Today, I got burned with a query that is about 1000x faster if the CTE is written to a real table.

The query itself is in the link, but I suspect it isn't important. To simplify, I needed a list of all the claims in an insurance policy where one claim met a certain condition (cat = 1).

A simplified version looks like this:

```
    with cat_claims as (select distinct pol_nbr from claims where cat = 1)

    select * from claims c
    inner join policies p on p.polnbr = c.polnbr
    inner join cat_claims cat on c.pol_nbr= cat.pol_nbr
```

which was super duper slow. If I rewrite it to look like this:

```
    with cat_claims as (select distinct claim_nbr from claims where cat = 1)

    select * into cat_claims
    from cat_claims

    select * from claims c
    inner join policies p on p.polnbr = c.polnbr
    inner join cat_claims cat on c.pol_nbr = cat.pol_nbr

    drop table cat_claims
```

it's way, way faster. This is odd to me.

**Question** Why would writing the CTE to an actual table provide a performance improvement?

Slow plan:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkyrpAtH4

Fast Plan:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ByGkAAKrN

Comment: The query is **always** important. This [other question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/221555/what-rules-determine-when-sql-server-use-a-cte-as-an-optimization-fence) might have some of the background info you're looking for.

Comment: Why so many SQL Server developers resist the use of statement terminators? (`;`) Do they like conffusing themselves and others? (the scripts above have 1 and 3 statements respectively while they look like 2 and 4)... Not to mention the error we'll get if we run them in a single batch.

Comment: My interpretation is that CTEs are not meant to make your query faster since they just act like a disposable view or as a temp results set. When joins are involved, a physical table (in your case or just creating a temp table) - the results are stored and evaluated once  vs for a CTE, they are for every row.  See https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/13112/8783

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though they are estimated plans and not the actual ones, the difference to me looks like it is coming from joining the tables: 
`RATING_CONTRIB_LOSS`,
`RATING_CONTRIB_USR`,
`cmbgrp`,
`rating_revision_set`, 
and the `Rating` table from the ratings `CTE`.

Joining these tables spawn huge table spools (lazy spool), that  could be even bigger on the actual plan.

[image]

For every row in the top part of the nested loops operator, the bottom result set is scanned resulting in

3361 rows * 3359 in the first `table spool` --> `Nested loops` --> `Top(1)`

and

1541 Rows * 3359 in the second `table spool` --> `Nested loops` --> `Top(1)`

[image]

These table spools are not present in either of the two plans in the temp table queries.

[image]

What I am getting at is that the query part that inserts into the table is alike to the corresponding query part of the `CTE`. There are some differences but I think that the major cause of the slowdown is because of the table spools.

An example of a difference is that the full table scan on  `RATING_CONTRIB_LOSS` in the `CTE` plan is changed to a scan with a residual predicate in the temp table plan.

**CTE**

[image]

**Temp table**

[image]
[image]

And you could argue that the second part of the query that uses the temp table might access the `RATING_CONTRIB_LOSS` table again. And I would have to agree because it will be doing an expensive key lookup.

[image]

**However**, the second table spool in the `CTE` plan is also based on a nested loops join with the`RATING_CONTRIB_LOSS` table, which is not present in the temp table plan, and that is a big plus.

**Conclusion**

I do believe that the difference in execution time comes from the query using the temp table's result in such a way that costly operators are not used. More specifically the Table spools. I would need the actual plan to be 100% sure.

As a sidenote, rewriting CTE's into temp tables or just splitting up queries in general can in many cases give better execution times.

It is easier to guess how many apples are in a bag with apples and pears than guess how many apples are in a bag with apples, pears, mango's, oranges, peaches, .... (Yes the fruit = tables).

I would also use actual #temp tables to store your intermediary results in.

---

### Comparison CTE & Temp table insert query parts

**Plan with CTE part 1**

[image]

**Plan with CTE part 2** 
[image]

**Plan with temp table part 1** 
[image]

Difference on RATING_CONTRIB_LOSS & Hash match join <> Nested Loops Join. Rest is very much alike, Same operations (2x) on Rating table